# How to assign a cancel button with an id to delete the given id from database in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-database

[This is our database from which I wanna assign the id to the delete it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz9Fv.jpg)

[this is how it will on HTML page the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BID0.jpg)

so the button used is an anchor tag and I am using a for loop to print all the entries in the database but now I want to delete the entry when the user clicks on cancel but since the to_id and from_id can be used multiple time I want to delete on the basis of the id column so can you suggest a way to do so

```
<div class="rowtemp">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="card card-signin1 my-5 cardpro" id="card" style=" max-width: 1600px;
                                                              max-height: 300px;
                                                              overflow: scroll;">
<div class="card-body "id="card">
<h2 style="color: #fafafa;">Challenge Requests Sent ({{ sent.count }})</h2>
<hr class="my-2" />
    {% if not sent %}
<h5><i>No sent requests!</i></h5>
    {% else %} {% for s_request in sent %}
<p style="color:white">{{s_request}}</p><br>
<br /><br />
    {% endfor %} {% endif %}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this like below:

```
# views.py

from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods


@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def delete_challenge_request(request, cr_id):
    try:
        cr = ChallengeRequest.objects.get(id=cr_id)
    except ChallengeRequest.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        cr.delete()

    return redirect('cr-list')


# urls.py

path('challenge-request/<int:id>/delete/', views.delete_challenge_request, name='cr-delete')

# template
{% for s_request in sent %}
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'cr-delete' s_request.pk %}">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="DELETE">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Above implementation includes view that deleted challenge request and redirects to challenge requests list view. If you don't want redirect and refresh the page dynamically, you can write javascript that sends AJAX request to your view and return JSON response from the view.

Comment: I now updated `except ChallengeRequest` to `except ChallengeRequest.DoesNotExist`. [Look at documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67050018/page-not-found-404-request-methodget-request-urlhttp-localhost8000-23
can you help me with this query, please