# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://localhost:8000/%23 Raised by:challengeide.views.send_challenge_request

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

[This is challenge page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io0vn.jpg)
When we go to ide page using the challenge button on the bottom and then click on submit button there then data is getting stored in database and function is running fine. But when I click on accept button and go to ide page and then click submit then data is not getting updated in database so basically function is not running and directly giving error 404 page not found.
[this is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K1oD.jpg)

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.urls import path,re_path
from . import views

app_name = 'challengeide'
urlpatterns = [

    path('challengeide/<int:sr_no>', views.show, name='show'),
    url('challengeide', views.qtn,name='test'),
    url('challenge/', views.challengeide, name='challengeide'),     
    url('#', views.send_challenge_request, name='send_challenge_request'),

]
```

this is my url.py

```
                                <small class="float-right">
                                    <div class="btn-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                                    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'challengeide:show' r_request.qtn_id %}">{% csrf_token %}
                                        <button class="btn btn-success mr-2" type="submit" value="Accept">Accept</button>
                                    </form>

                                </div>
                                </small>
```

this is my template for challenge page which has accept button

```
                                    <a
                                    class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
                                    href="{% url 'challengeide:send_challenge_request' %}"
                                    >Submit</a
```

this is my template for challenge ide which has the submit button

```
def send_challenge_request(request):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=to_id)
    print(user)
    score = ChallengeDemo.objects.filter(from_id=request.user,to_id=user,qtn_id=a)  
    print(score)
    if(len(score)==0):
        print("dataintial")
        print(to_id)
        global data2
        #user = data2
        print(request.user)
        print(user)
        print("dataentry")
        entry = ChallengeDemo(
        from_id=request.user,
        to_id=user,
        score1 = int(counter)+(fspace/ftime),
        score2 = 0,
        qtn_id = a
        )
        entry.save()
        print("dataexit")
        exit
    else:
        print("updating score 2")
        score.score2=int(counter)+(fspace/ftime)
        score.save()
        print("dataexit")
        return render(request,'index.html')
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

this the views.py where i am trying to add the data to database which works fine when i click on submit via challenge button on challenge page but fails and gives error when i do the same via accept button on challenge page

Comment: Where do you get `to_id` from : `user = get_object_or_404(User, id=to_id)`

Comment: Declared to_id global and it's working now.
Thank you.